# How to access MySQL with XQuery in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xquery, zorba

I am new to PHP and I only heard about Zorba. Basically we need to convert MySQL tables into our JSON format through XQuery.

Is there a library to connect Zorba to MySQL ? It also seems that Zorba needs a native extension on the destination server and that makes it pretty useless to us.

We'd like to use XQuery because our entire system is basing on and we've to cope hundreds of queries.

Thank you

Comment: Needing be be able to handle "hundreds of queries" is probably not a great reason for moving from MySQL to a NoSQL database.  Rather needing to go to a schema-less (JSON) or similar data structure should be the driving reason.  I don't understand what Xquery would have to do with this though since that deals with querying XML structures.

Comment: Not sure if Zorba is your requirement - if so, I don't know the situation with Zorba.  But if your requirement is an XQuery-based native XML database, [eXist-db](http://exist-db.org) has a SQL module that lets you query SQL databases.  See http://atomic.exist-db.org/HowTo/SQLDatabases/.

Comment: @MikeBrant. Yes I know that sounds odd but to keep our db queries in a portable format and life simple, we choose to use XQuery, also when using MySQL&Co end-points. By hundreds, I rather meant that we've hundreds of such  queries stored in XQuery format and they rather act as gate between db storage systems or formats for us. In Java this was easy to implement.

Comment: @joewiz. Its Java, and there I've it done. I need exactly the same as PHP, and this without exotic native PHP extensions. I am wondering now thats possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Zorba recently got a JDBC module that allows you to connect to any JDBC data source allowing you to do queries or updates. The documentation for the module is available at http://www.zorba.io/documentation/2.9/modules/www.zorba-xquery.com_modules_jdbc.html.